# Facebook: How to get back the short PID from an FBID for a photo?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code to post a photo to my applications photo album.  My question is how can i convert the FBID that this code returns into a shore PID for the photo?

```
$file= 'test.jpg';
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

This returns an array with ID being the FBID of the photo uploaded.  I need the PID of the photo.

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to use photo.addtag and i need the Userid_shortpid to use the old rest api to tag photos.  (the new graph api has yet to implement addtag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  For anyone who wants to know i did FQL like this:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE object_id = "FBID"
```

Comment: is this FQL still working? coz i want to know the image URL of the uploaded image. thanks,

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not working for me. I am usong the Graph API to upload a picture, get the resulting $fbid but I am not able to retrieve the $pid with the query you are describing. Is there another line of code I am missing?